# How to call getElementById() on XSLT output?

Tags: php, getelementbyid

Using PHP, I have transformed an XML document using `XSLTProcessor::transformToDoc()` into another XML document (of type `DOMDocument`.)

I want to call `getElementById()` on this resulting `DOMDocument`, but it does not know which attribute to look at.  It seems I have to tell it somehow that the "id" attribute is the one containing each element's ID.

I can't see how to do this however.  I don't have a DTD so I can't call `DOMDocument::validate()`, I can't set `DOMDocument::validateOnParse` as the `DOMDocument` instance doesn't exist until the transform has been completed and by then it's too late, and I can't call `DOMElement::setIdAttribute()` because I would have to manually run through every single element to do this.

Is there any way to easily be able to call `getElementById()` on the output of an XSLT transform, in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution which works (not sure about the efficiency though) is to use XPath instead:

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($xml);
$nodes = $xp->evaluate('//*[@id="blah"]');
$node = $nodes->item(0);
```